# Why is GetMethods() of a parameterized generic interface returning a non-parameterized MethodInfo

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, interface

Given these interfaces:

```
public interface IGenericBase<T>
{
    T MyMethod<T>(T arg1);
}

public interface IGenericDescendant : IGenericBase<int>
{
}
```

Using the type of IGenericDescendant, I get the set of interfaces via GetInterfaces().  As expected, this returns a "resolved" (parameterized) type: IGenericBase`1 with T resolved to Int32.  I then invoke GetMethods on said interface type, expecting to get a similarly resolved version of MyMethod, but instead I get the generic version with T as an unresolved type argument.

```
var type = typeof(IGenericDescendant);    
foreach (var super in type.GetInterfaces())
{
    foreach (var member in super.GetMethods())
    {
        yield return member;  // Get MyMethod<T> not MyMethod<Int32>
    }
}
```

According to Microsoft's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td205ybf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), this is not correct behavior for GetMethods():

> If the current T:System.Type represents a constructed generic type,
>   this method returns the MethodInfo objects with the type parameters
>   replaced by the appropriate type arguments

Unfortunately, when it comes to a type resolved generic interface, that just doesn't seem to be the case.

As a work-around, I could use MakeGenericType() to resolve the type arguments, but I'd have to know the types, which means I'd essentially have to resolve the type arguments by name myself by traversing up through the hierarchy.  That's easy for this concrete example, but I need a general solution.  Surely I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Please remove or rename the generic method specification from `IGenericBase<T>.MyMethod`.  I don't think you intended on duplicating the same type parameter name in both the interface and the method (the compiler creates a warning for this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyMethod` is a generic method declared in generic interface. It still remains a generic method if you specify parameters for generic type. For example:

```
IGenericDescendant x = new SomeImplementation();
x.MyMethod<string>("abc"); // method is still generic

IGenericBase<int> y = new SomeOtherImplementation();
y.MyMethod<string>("abc"); // still can do that
```

You probably wanted to declare interface as

```
public interface IGenericBase<T>
{
    T MyMethod(T arg1);
}
```

Comment: The compiler warning that the type name `T` is redefined was likely ignored.  If the method were declared as `MyMethod<U>`, then it would have been worked as expected.

Comment: Wow, good catch, that should have been obvious.  Thanks!  And Steve, you're right about the warning.